# Best method for getting JSON from REST API with Token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a rest API which has some nice JSON I want. I want to be able to call the API from a script within some HTML and pull out the JSON thats relevant to me.

What would be my best approach?

Something like the below using ajax? but i can't find a nice working example.

I have a token for my API so its vital I can use this. A curl command would be perfect, alas I cant do that. Eventually what I do will be used in a chrome extension.

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'https://my-api.com/rest/v2/users/'
    type: 'GET',
    data: { content: 'testing test' },
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", "BEARER " + xxxxxxxxx );
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        // response
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var myJson;
 $.ajax( {
  url: 'https://my-api.com/rest/v2/users/'
  type: 'GET',
  data: { content: 'testing test' },
  headers: { 'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + token },
  success: function( response ) {
    myJson = response;
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is the official explanation of the getJSON() method with some examples
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

```
var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxx";
function xRequest(endpoint, method, options) {
  $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: method,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.xxxx.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.xxxxxx+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
```

This works